# Apache in XAMPP won't start

Tags: xampp

Here's a clue: when I go to localhost, the screen for IIS7 comes up. How do I disable that, because that is sure what is listening on Port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answered post by user382738 solved it for me. Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services > and set both "WebClient" and "Web Deployment Agent Service" services to disabled. Then I changed the Config to listen on port 1234 because Port 80 was still not working. Apache was running. Type "localhost:1234" in the browser and all is working!